# Is there an angularjs equivalent to rails number_to_human?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I would like to turn `1234010` into `1.2M`

In rails I would do `number_to_human( 1234010 )`, is there an angularjs filter that is equivalent or do I need to roll my own?

Also, is there a place to see all the angularjs built in filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bring in a library like [Humanize+](http://github.hubspot.com/humanize/) and create your own filter...

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('numberToHuman', function() {
    return function(num, precision) {
        return Humanize.compactInteger(num, precision);
    };
});
```

---

```
<div ng-app="app">
    {{ 1234010 | numberToHuman: 1 }}
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gsmqgms/)

List of built in angular filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter